# error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cygwin, porting

im trying to port application from cygwin to visual studio 2008 express
but im getting this error :

```
error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
```

in this type of code:

```
if (!strcasecmp("A0", s))  ....
```

what is the replacement in vs? i can't find any thing in the net

Answer (score 49):

add this to your precompiled header (or some other config.h)

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
//not #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) because we have strncasecmp in mingw
#define strncasecmp _strnicmp
#define strcasecmp _stricmp
#endif
```

Answer (score 10):

Look for

```
int _stricmp(
   const char *string1,
   const char *string2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you expand a little?  Is strcasecmp replaced now for the vs libraries?

Comment: @Meep strcasecmp() is a function specified by posix, which MSVC does not support.