# Visual Studio and GCC - Compiler differences

Tags: c, linux, gcc

when compiling in VS i get no error but with gcc i get the following:

```
warning: format ‘%Lf’ expects argument of type ‘long double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%Lf",&checkprice);
  ^
/tmp/cch8NUeU.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x8e1): undefined reference to `stricmp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess this is normal. How can i fix it in gcc?

Comment: Declare `checkprice` as a `long double`? And `stricmp` is not a standard function. I think you need `strcasecmp` for POSIX systems.

Comment: I dunno if there is a portable `stricmp`.  It's `strcasecmp` in POSIX, but that's `<strings.h>`, not `<string.h>`.  You may need to wrap this in your own platform agnostic function with some `#ifdefs` to select either `strcasecmp` or `stricmp`.

Comment: "%Lf" --> "%lf" this indeed worked..

Comment: Oh, and doesn't VS compiler warn you about the `scanf()` specifier? does it have warnings turned on? The other function could be solved with a `#ifdef` as suggested in other comments.

Comment: strcasecmp also did the trick with these libraries only:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694723/error-c3861-strcasecmp-identifier-not-found-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stricmp()` is not a standard function, though there is a POSIX equivalent [`strcasecmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcasecmp.3.html) so for your code to compile seamlessly with both compilers you can add something like this

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define _stricmp strcasecmp
#endif
```

and use [`_stricmp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/k59z8dwe.aspx) since `stricmp()` was [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms235365.aspx).

Also fix the `scanf()` format specifier, or change the destination variable type to `long double`.

Comment: thanks! everything worked out! i did not quite catch the part "deprecated", why should i create a function _stricmp (with the underscore).

Comment: @falsobuio Read in the link, those functions are not recommended in new code. They still work primarily for compatibility with older code.